# Apache web server, how to read a file in users folder?

Tags: html, apache

I am very new to web programming.  I am running Apache on a raspberry pi. The web page I created needs to read a text file and display it on a page.
This works great if the text file is in /var/www/html.  However, I create this file in a user account in a folder which is /home/pi/Programming/WeatherStation_0.1
There doesn't seem that I can do so.  I receive no errors.
Here is the web page function code.

```
Weather<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Phidgets</title>
</head>
<script>
    function connectWeatherData({fetch('http://192.168.1.33/home/pi/Programming/WeatherStation_0.1/data.csv')>
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        var data = text.split("\n");
        document.getElementById("dataLabel").innerHTML = data[data.length ->
    })
}
```

The fetch command no longer works when I specify this path.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Imagine this would just work and all your secret and private files including passwords could be read by everyone just by typing it in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP server (listening on `http://192.168.1.33`) needs to be configured to provide the file for the URL that you are requesting.

Mapping paths to the filesystem starting at `/var/www/html` is a configuration for an HTTP system.

What that configuration (and no aliases, rewrites or similar set up), when you ask for `/home/pi/Programming/WeatherStation_0.1/data.csv` the server will try to find a file at `/var/www/html/home/pi/Programming/WeatherStation_0.1/data.csv`.

`/var/www/html/home/pi/Programming/WeatherStation_0.1/data.csv`, presumably, does not exist on the server.

You've given no indication that you've changed the configuration of the server.

Possibly you want to change where the file is created, maybe using [Per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)

---

You would also need to deal with permissions. Generally speaking, user home directories are configured to allow access only by the user to whom they belong to.

The webserver won't run as that user, so you need to [give it permission](https://www.cade.utah.edu/faqs/what-permissions-should-i-set-my-public_html-directory-to/).

Comment: Sounds like I need to use per user web directories.

Comment: I seem to be getting nowhere fast. I have since enabled per user directories. I created the web page in my users folder pi/public_html and updated the web page code.  If now have fetch('http://192.168.1.33/~pi/public_html/data.csv')> and tried other combinations. I cannot seem to get this to work.  permissions are OK.